# VB.NET - Find a string in a XML String

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, webforms, infopath

I am working on a project to read InfoPath XML files into a .NET form. I'm trying to get the .xsn version from the href in order to determine what version of the InfoPath form I should display. Since there is only 1 .xsn string in the XML File, I can use that, but I'm having trouble parsing out the file name.

```
http://servername/foldername/forms/fileNameV100.xsn
```

Comment: Are you just trying to parse the file name out of a `String` or are you utilizing something like `XPath`?

Comment: Just trying to parse the string to the "filename" part of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would parse the filename.  You can use these techniques to parse out the version.  Additional notes are in the comments of the code.

```
Private Function ParseXsnFileName(ByVal strTarget As String) As String

    Dim strResult As String = String.Empty

    'Get the location of where the .xsn extension starts.
    Dim intExtensionLocation As Integer = strTarget.IndexOf(".xsn")

    If intExtensionLocation >= 0 Then

        'Now we will initiate a loop that iterates back character by character until we find 
        'the forward slash of the URL that preceedes the filename.
        Dim bolStartFound As Boolean = False
        Dim intCursor As Integer = intExtensionLocation

        Do Until intCursor = 0 OrElse bolStartFound

            If strTarget.Substring(intCursor, 1) = "/" Then

                'Setting this to true exist the loop.
                bolStartFound = True

            End If

            intCursor -= 1

        Loop

        If bolStartFound Then

            'We found all of the pieces we need to parse out the filename.

            'Add 2 because of the "intCursor -= 1" and because we don't want the / in the filename.
            Dim intStartLocation As Integer = intCursor + 2

            'Add 4 to StartLocation because we want the extension.
            'Subtract intStartLocation from intExtensionLocation to get the length.
            strResult = strTarget.Substring(intStartLocation, (intExtensionLocation - (intStartLocation + 4)))

        End If

    End If

    Return strResult

End Function
```

Example Usage:

```
    Dim strParseThis As String = "http://servername/foldername/forms/fileNameV100.xsn"

    Dim strFileName As String = ParseXsnFileName(strParseThis)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed

Comment: You're welcome.  Please mark this as the accepted answer so this does not remain as an outstanding question without an accepted answer.